# android full screen an activity and hide key bar

Tags: java, android, android-fullscreen

i am new in android programming!
i want a full screen image like Hill Climb Racing (as you can see below)

[image: Hill Climb Racing]

i try to use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

but it just disappear action bar and i want to disappear both action bar and android default  key bar (home button, back and the another one)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are targeting android 4.0 and higher

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Check this [developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html#40) for more detail information

Comment: but how can i keep this? and hide it again? i override onTouch event but key bar still appeare. :(

Comment: from the points given in the developer site... i think this is not possible. Did u check this link https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

Comment: yep! i find the answer, we should put that in onResume no onTouch !! thanks again for your help!

Comment: i dont know whether this will help ur query since hiding bar would stop your navigation. Lets see if someone comes up with a better solution

Comment: while mentioned targeting android 4.0 why it appear warning for View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN ?

Answer (score 3):

try this in your activity on the manifest

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```